# How to know which test is currently triggered

Tags: java, junit

I have next code

```
class Test extend Parent{

 @Test
  public void testMethod(){
  };
}

class Parent {
  'here I need to have some check which test is running now'
}
```

As far as Parent class is initialized before Test class, how to know which jUnit test is running right now or which child class if there are multiple?

Comment: Why? The whole idea of unit tests is that they are independend.

Comment: long story short, it's gonna be tests for monolith and I need to override configs for some tests, one option is to do it via jenkins job by overriding env variables, but this way I asked would be more painless

Comment: A parent class has no knowledge of its children, the child specific code should be in the child anyway.

Comment: You can easily tell the classname of the test file even in the parent. Is that enough? Not the testfunction name though.

Comment: yes, think it's enough, how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

**You can get the name of the descendant class** that initiates the parent class creation by:

`// in the constructor of the parent
System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getClassName());`

In case of multiple inheritance level you can write a bit of extra custom logic and traverse the current stacktrace.

*Disclaimer: what you are about to do does not seem nice. Using built-in features, like `@Before`, `@BeforeClass` or some refactoring might be a better solution.*